# Show that $f(z)=\dfrac{z-1}{iz+i}$ maps circles passing through $z=-1$ into straight lines.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that

> $f(z)=\dfrac{z-1}{iz+i}$ maps circles passing through $z=-1$ into straight lines.

Writing a point on such a circle as $z=-1+re^{i\theta}$+$re^{i\phi}$, for some fixed $\theta$, gives $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{i}(\frac{-2}{re^{i\theta}+ re^{i\phi}}+1)$. But this doesn't look like a line to me.  Is my circle not right or is this actually a line?

Here is why I say this is a circle through $-1$.  $\theta$ is fixed.  $\mid(−1+re^{iθ}+re^{iϕ})-(−1+re^{iθ})\mid=\mid re^{iϕ}\mid=r$, so the points $z=−1+re^{iθ}+re^{iϕ}$ lie on a circle of radius r centered at $z_{0}=−1+re^{iθ}$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why that's a circle. Now why do you think that other thing doesn't look like a line?

Comment: Because the angle $\phi$ is varying, right?

Comment: So you think its a line?

Comment: Not exactly sure what your asking.  $\theta$ is what determines the center of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $w=\dfrac{1}{i}\left(\dfrac{-2}{re^{i\theta}+re^{i\phi}}+1\right)$ then $\dfrac{1-iw}{2}=\dfrac{1}{re^{i\theta}+re^{i\phi}}$ then
$$1=|e^{i\phi}|=\left|\dfrac{2}{r(1-iw)}-e^{i\theta}\right|$$
or
$$\left|w-\left(\dfrac{2ie^{-i\theta}}{r}-i\right)\right|=|w+i|$$
which is the locus of points equidistant from points $\dfrac{2ie^{-i\theta}}{r}-i$ and $-i$, that's a line.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the circle through $-1$ with centre at $a$ is
$$|z-a|=|-1-a|=|a+1|.\tag1$$
If $w=f(z)=(z-1)/(iz+i)$ then $z=(iw+1)/(-iw+1)$. Putting this into $(1)$
gives
$$\left|\frac{iw+1}{-iw+1}-a\right|=|a+1|$$
equivalently
$$|iw+1+a(iw-1)|=|a+1||iw-1|$$
that is
$$|(1+a)iw+1-a|=|a+1||iw-1|$$
or
$$\left|w-i\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right|=|w+i|.$$
This is the locus of points equidistant from $-i$ and $i(a-1)/(a+1)$.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks.